# LDAP Authentication using DirectoryEntry

Tags: c#, ldap, authentication

We use to authenticate user on AD using the following DirectoryEntry constructor:

```
new DirectoryEntry(path, domainName + "\\" + UserName, Password);
```

It use to work fine until the Domain Controller was changed.

Now to make it work we have to use:

```
new DirectoryEntry(path,  UserName, Password);
```

Can anyone please explain difference and why the second method is working now and first is not working?

Note: I am not sure but I think the domain functional level where raised to Server 2008  from Server 2003. Does it make difference?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know exactly why this ever worked :-) and therefore I cannot really explain why the other option works now....

If you work on .NET 3.5, you can use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace and easily verify your credentials:

```
// create a "principal context" - e.g. your domain (could be machine, too)
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN"))
{
    // validate the credentials
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword")
}
```

It's simple, it's reliable, it's 100% C# managed code on your end - what more can you ask for? :-)

Comment: Thanks for reply reason iam asking for help is code is under production envoirment and there are different AD on different deployments.We need to understand when we require domain name with user and when we dont need it.

Comment: @buzz: typically, I would assume no domain - since the domain is really already part of the LDAP path. Also: typically I would use some LDAP name, e.g. the distinguished name `CN=Buzz Aldrin,CN=Users,DC=YourDomain,DC=com` rather than just a Windows user name...

Comment: Thanks it was usefull, if any one has explnation for existing scenario it will be helpfull because at this moment it is not easy to update code base, we are trying to identify what changes on AD could lead to this result.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the path used for this follow this format is

```
DirectoryEntry("LDAP//:domainName");
```

domainName can be either an url like : my.ldapDomain.com

or a distinguishedName like : DC=My,DC=ldapDomain,DC=COM

I'm afraid we can't give you more informations about why your code worked before and not now, since we can't see the content of the variable "path" and "domainName" used in your code.

Please provide more informations